# Is it possible accelerate a network flow speed at a midway point

Tags: network-programming, operating-system, udpclient

[Here is a simple network with three hosts and a switch. A UDP flow is source from h1 to h2 with speed of 1Mbit/s. I enforce forwarding rules on the switch, which will forward the flow to h3. I wonder if we can do something to the flow on h3 to accelerate the flow speed to 1.2Mbit/s. This is just an example, the speed before and after may vary. The question is that if it possible to accelerate flow speed at a midway point. And how to do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u62Z.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with programming, does it?

Comment: I have tried libpcap library to capture packet on a middle host then replay it. I think it may need programming to achieve it.